# Remove page from Search Result Bunch

Tags: google, robots.txt, search-engine-indexing, rich-snippets

When I do a branded search for a website the structure shows like ( see image ). I would love to remove Privacy Policy page or Manipulate the structure I see now ( showing pages I want to ). How I can do it?

[image: Example of what I were saying]

I already added robots - nosnippet meta tag to remove all rich snippets from a page, but it didn't work. Are there any other methods except removing page from indexation?

Answer (score 1):

Those six indented links under your main entry on Google are known as *Site Links*. These are automatically created by Google for websites based on a special algorithm which looks at page popularity and end-user journeys through your site. You can’t add Site Links to your Google search listings, however you can ask for specific pages to be excluded from your Site Links, such as your Privacy Policy.

1. Login to [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) and select the website you wish to configure (*taskmatics.com*).
2. Navigate using the menu on the left to: *Search Appearance* | *Site Links*.
3. Enter the Privacy Policy URL (*http://taskmatics.com/privacy-policy/*) into the text field captioned "*Demote this sitelink URL:*" and then click the *Demote* button.

You can find more information about the [SiteLinks feature](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) in Google Webmaster Tools help documentation.

Comment: Please don't answer a question which should be closed.